# MPI program hangs or states connection refused when specifing to use a specific port

Tags: mpi, connection-refused

I am trying to build a mini cluster in which I have a single master and (currently) 1 slave.

When I type the command

```
mpirun --mca bt1_tcp_if_exclude "p2p1,lo,virbr0,virbr0-nic" -n 5 -v -show-progress --display-map -hostfile my_hostfile.txt my_mpi_program -in infile
```

which gives the following output

```
Data for JOB [1392,1] offset 0

 ========================   JOB MAP   ========================

Data for node: mschramm Num slots: 4    Max slots: 4    Num procs: 4
Process OMPI jobid: [1392,1] App: 0 Process rank: 0
Process OMPI jobid: [1392,1] App: 0 Process rank: 1
Process OMPI jobid: [1392,1] App: 0 Process rank: 2
Process OMPI jobid: [1392,1] App: 0 Process rank: 3

Data for node: client_1 Num slots: 4    Max slots: 4    Num procs: 1
Process OMPI jobid: [1392,1] App: 0 Process rank: 4

=============================================================
App launch reported: 2 (out of 2) daemons - 0 (out of 5) procs
App launch reported: 2 (out of 2) daemons - 4 (out of 5) procs
[mschramm][[1392,1],0][btl_tcp_endpoint.c:818:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect] connect() to 192.168.122.1 failed: Connection refused (111)
```

This says that the connection was refused due to 192.168.122.1 but I have stated to exclude it in the original command (--mca bt1_tcp_if_exclude "p2p1,lo,virbr0,virbr0-nic")

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

The MPI program will either halt (as seen above) or it will hang. It seems random.

After being told it is "l" and not "1"... I got the following error

```
App launch reported: 2 (out of 2) daemons - 4 (out of 6) procs [mschramm][[6062,1],0] 
[btl_tcp_endpoint.c:818:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect] 
[mschramm][[6062,1],1 [btl_tcp_endpoint.c:818:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect] connect() to 192.168.1.118 failed: No route to host (113) connect() to 192.168.1.118 failed: No route to host (113)
```

Running the following commands on Master Node

```
[mpi_user@mschramm ~]$ ifconfig em1
em1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.143  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::8d16:c4ff:a398:26c1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether f8:b1:56:cd:91:f1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 15649  bytes 2240360 (2.1 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 35427  bytes 34470024 (32.8 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7200000-f7220000 

[mpi_user@mschramm ~]$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.27.15.254    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 p2p1
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 em1
10.27.12.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 p2p1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 em1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0
```

And on the first client node

```
[mpi_user@client_1 ~]$ ifconfig em1
em1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.118  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::1b26:a452:58ac:1cdd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 fe80::8d16:c4ff:a398:26c1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether f8:b1:56:cd:97:74  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 36341  bytes 34562000 (32.9 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 14544  bytes 2126373 (2.0 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7100000-f7120000

[mpi_user@client_1 ~]$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 em1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 em1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0
```

Comment: you have a typo. it should be `btl_tcp_if_exclude` instead of `bt1_tcp_if_exclude` (e.g. replace the number `1` with lower case letter `L`)

Comment: Well, I'm slightly embarrassed by that.... But now I am getting a no route to host. I can easily ssh back and forth so I don't know where to go next.
App launch reported: 2 (out of 2) daemons - 4 (out of 6) procs
[mschramm][[6062,1],0][btl_tcp_endpoint.c:818:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect] [mschramm][[6062,1],1][btl_tcp_endpoint.c:818:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect] connect() to 192.168.1.118 failed: No route to host (113)
connect() to 192.168.1.118 failed: No route to host (113)

Comment: what if you `mpirun --mca btl_tcp_if_include 192.168.1.0/24 ...` instead ?

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error... I also tried _ifinclude em1 which would the the correct interface.

Comment: is `em1` the right interface on both nodes ? are both nodes in the same subnet ? did you check there is **no** firewall on any of the hosts ? can you `ifconfig em1; netstat -nr` on both nodes and edit your question ?

Comment: Edited the original post. 
Thank you

Comment: what about firewalls ? (simply run `iptables -L` as root on both nodes).

Comment: It ended up being a firewall issue on the client. 
Thank you for all your help.